# Django global statics and templates

Tags: django, templates, static, global

Where should I place statics and templates that area used for more than one app?

I'm currently doing this:

> /projectname
>
> --/appname
>
> --/projectname
>
> --/static
>
> ----/projectname (statics that are used for more than one app here)
>
> ------/images
>
> ------/javascripts
>
> ------/stylesheets
>
> ----/appname
>
> ------/images
>
> ------/javascripts
>
> ------/stylesheets
>
> --/templates
>
> ----/projectname (templates that are used for more than one app here)
>
> ----/appname

Answer (score 0):

Have a `shared` dir in your templates and in your `static` dir.